# Atualizar/Sincronizar Projeto no Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web no codeigniter e irá ter um link para atualizar a versão do projeto quando tiver uma atualização.
Ou seja, o cliente vai acessar o sistema, irá aparecer uma mensagem avisando que há atualizações pendentes, o usuário clica no link e o projeto é atualizado para a versão mais recente.

Como posso fazer essa lógica? Estou utilizando o framework Codeigniter.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, o que pode fazer é usar o $_GET para criar uma URL e ao acessar atualizar o que precisa, isso pode ser feito no index().
Exemplo:

```
   url = http://localhost/articles?update=1 
   if ($_GET['update'] == '1') {
        aqui voce cria uma função nome_da_função() e criar a lógica do update.
    };
```

Link do GET : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php